# Google Play: Can't RELEASE TO PRODUCTION because "a draft release in production already", what to do?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am trying to release a new version of my app at Google Play Console.

I have one version which I didn't release and then I uploaded a new one to Beta that I want to release.

When I press on the "RELEASE TO PRODUCTION" button I get the following message:

> "To release to production, ensure that you don't have a draft release
>   in production already"

If I try to "RELEASE TO PRODUCTION" the former version I get the same message. How can I break this loop? any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42056104/4146722

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a Play Store question and not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines. We are not support for third-party sites.

Comment: While it may be marked as off topic, it certainly helped me figure out my problem.  Not sure what the issue is.  It has 57 votes up and the answer had 108 votes up so it certainly seems to be a helpful question and answer.

Answer (score 185, accepted):

At some point you probably hit "Create release" while you were in the Production Management page then left the draft there. Go and Edit that draft and click "Discard" on it then you'll be able to move an app from Beta to Prod

Comment: There is no "Production Management" category at Google Play Console right now. Please update the category name.

Comment: Yeah, under Production section there is a button "MANAGE PRODUCTION" (uppercase). Makes sense ?

Comment: this was a case for me..it helped out.. just clicked on "Edit release" and Discard previously saved settings.. then moved to production

Comment: Thanks, their UI makes no sense to me, have to "google" how to use it constantly

Comment: Now it just says "Production" :-) Tx everybody!